# Why can certain commands be ran through a variable, while others can't?

Tags: bash, command

So if I put some simple commands into a variable, and then call that variable at the beginning of the line, it actually uses those commands. For example:

```
yes@no:~$ nnn="ls -l Super"
yes@no:~$ $nnn
-rw-rw-rw- 1 yes yes 6 May 29 19:46 Super
```

But if I try it with anything that has any special characters, or if I try with something like `case` or `if`, it doesn't work:

```
yes@no:~$ nnn="ls -l|grep Super"
yes@no:~$ $nnn
ls: invalid option -- '\'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

Or:

```
yes@no:~$ duper="if [[ ${ar} -eq 2 ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi"
yes@no:~$ "$duper"
if [[  -eq 2 ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi: command not found
```

Obviously there's something deeper here that I do not understand.

Comment: Related: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Answer (score 0):

The quote wrapping is escaping the special characters, so they are being treated as literals.  To elicit the behaviour you are looking for, you would have to do

```
eval "$nnn"
eval "$duper"
```

Comment: But everywhere I read, using eval is somehow 'evil'

Comment: I can't speak for the morality of it :-) but for some things it's necessary – case in point.  I would be inclined to ask what problem you are trying to solve by running commands in this manner?  Perhaps there's another approach without resorting to evil `eval`.

Comment: I was just generally curious. it helps with understanding things on a more fundamental level, little by little.